# Error when building with Android Annotations

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, android-annotations

I'm using the guide [here](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Eclipse-Project-Configuration) to integrate Android Annotations in my Eclipse project (no Maven). I've got the latest ADT running, and tried cleaning my project, double checking build paths and order/export, and turning annotations on and off, but whenever I add the Android Annotations jar to the entries under `Java Compiler > Annotation Processing > Factory Path` in Eclipse, I get this error:

```
Error
Mon Jul 15 18:01:05 PDT 2013
Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project 'Shopping'.

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/androidannotations/annotations/EActivity
    at org.androidannotations.AndroidAnnotationProcessor.getSupportedAnnotationTypes(AndroidAnnotationProcessor.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.dispatch.ProcessorInfo.<init>(ProcessorInfo.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.apt.pluggable.core.dispatch.IdeAnnotationProcessorManager.discoverNextProcessor(IdeAnnotationProcessorManager.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.dispatch.RoundDispatcher.round(RoundDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.dispatch.BaseAnnotationProcessorManager.processAnnotations(BaseAnnotationProcessorManager.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.apt.pluggable.core.dispatch.IdeAnnotationProcessorManager.processAnnotations(IdeAnnotationProcessorManager.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.processAnnotations(Compiler.java:820)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.AbstractImageBuilder.compile(AbstractImageBuilder.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.BatchImageBuilder.compile(BatchImageBuilder.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.AbstractImageBuilder.compile(AbstractImageBuilder.java:302)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.BatchImageBuilder.build(BatchImageBuilder.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.buildAll(JavaBuilder.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.build(JavaBuilder.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:726)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:292)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:295)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:256)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:394)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project$1.run(Project.java:618)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.internalBuild(Project.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.build(Project.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.util.CoreUtility$BuildJob.run(CoreUtility.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.androidannotations.annotations.EActivity
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 29 more
```

Anyone have a fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be a bug with my snapshot of Android Annotations. Reverting to the stable 2.7.1 works!

Comment: both 2.7.1 and 3.0-SNAPSHOT work for me. Just make sure api goes to compile while no-api jar is only used as annotation processor

Answer (score 1):

You might have copied the wrong of the 2 jars. Please check carefully, where you place the one with and without "api" in the name (as given on the configuration page).

Besides that I guess you have checked all steps from the [trouble shooting section](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Eclipse-Project-Configuration#troubleshooting).

Comment: Checked troubleshooting already, but nothing applies. I have the API lib listed under Android Private Libraries and physically located in `libs` folder, which is checked to be exported, and I have tried placing the non-API jar in both `compile-libs` and `lib` to no avail.